# How do I mark an Evolve migration complete?

Tags: mysql, database-migration, evolve

I am using Evolve to manage database migrations. I made a schema update directly to the database without using Evolve, then created a migration script, and now I need Evolve to recognize that it's already been done. How can I do that?

The Evolve site says [this](https://evolve-db.netlify.app/faq/#i-classfas-fa-checki-can-i-mark-a-migration-as-already-executed-):

> *Can I mark a migration as already executed?*
>
> Yes! Sometimes a hotfix
> is quickly applied in production without a proper Evolve migration. To
> ensure consistency across all environments, a migration matching those
> changes must be added to version control but skip in production. Use
> the option `SkipNextMigrations` to fix this issue.

I followed the [syntax example given in GitHub](https://github.com/lecaillon/Evolve/issues/190#issuecomment-779473743) but it tells me that it's an unrecognized option (I tried `--skip-next-migrations true` as well as `--SkipNextMigrations`).

For example:

```
./evolve migrate mysql -c "$CONNECTION_STRING" -l ../migrations --command-timeout 36000 --skip-next-migrations true
```

Answer (score 0):

The ability to skip migrations was introduced with version 3.0.0.

[Evolve releases](https://github.com/lecaillon/Evolve/releases)

The syntax is:

```
./evolve migrate mysql -c "$CONNECTION_STRING" -l <path-to-migration-files> --command-timeout 36000 --skip-next-migrations true
```